# I'm trying to connect to a SQL Express Server on my machine using sqlalchemy but I'm getting an error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Express Server on my machine using sqlalchemy but I'm getting an error. Here is the code I have:

```
import sqlalchemy as sal
import pandas as pd

sqlcon=sal.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@' + 'DESKTOP-A1BUCDR\SQLEXPRESS' + '/' + 'Northwind' + '?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server')

df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from Orders', sqlcon)
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what I may be getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL evaluates to:

```
mssql+pyodbc://@DESKTOP-A1BUCDR\\SQLEXPRESS/Northwind?driver=ODBC+Driver+13
+for+SQL+Server
```

The errors points to not finding the data source name (DSN), which I think you must not want to use since you give what looks like a hostname and a driver parameter.

That's fine too:

```
mssql+pyodbc://<UID>:<PWD>@DESKTOP-A1BUCDR:1433/Northwind?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server
```

If your port is the default (1433), you don’t really need to add it.

Why is your hostname `DESKTOP-A1BUCDR\SQLEXPRESS` ? and why are you using `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server` and not a more recent version ?

You could instead try using a [`URL built for your hostname`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections) or directly the [`pyODBC string`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string).

Comment: Thanks. I don't have any prior experience with these packages. At the moment this is what I have: sqlcon = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://@DESKTOP-A1BUCDR:1433/Northwind?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server") . I guessed the port number I need to verify it. I removed the password and the username as I'm current;y using windows authentication to login, I don't enter any credentials. How is this line of code so far?.

Comment: I should have removed SQLEXPRESS. I made a mistake in writing my hostname. With regards to the ODBC Driver 13 I made the mistake of thinking I didn't need to change it.

Comment: I’ve only ever used the URL with credentials, but your URL in the comment looks good if it’s possible not to have user:password at the beginning.